# Regex Parse Email Python

Tags: python, regex

So here's a sample of an e-mail I want to parse, to extract ONLY its body.

```
RECEIVED: 2012-11 20 09:59:24
SUBJECT: Get Boddy
--- Original Sender: Mark Twain. ---

----- Original Message -----
From: Boby Indo
To: Obum Hunter 
At: 11/20  9:59:22

***NEW ISSUE SUPPORTED THROUGH UNIVERSALITY   vs 104-13 on AY 3s JAN   
10+BB {MYXV ABC 4116    SM  MYXV YA 102-15 <DO>} | 2010/11 4.0s             4.0s
6+ BB {MYXV ABC 4132    NS  MYXV YT 102-22 <DO>} | 2010 4.5s                4.5s
ABO 2006-OP1 M1     00442PAG5     19-24      p5 
***SECOND SUPPORTED TRHOUGH INVERSALITY GEVINGS                      
10+BB  {NXTW VXA 4061   SL  MYXV YA 103-22 <DO>} | 11 wala 3.5s             3.5s
10+BB  {NXTW VXA 12-47  SP  MYXV YA 106-20 <DO>} | 22 wala 4.0s             4.0s

------------------------------------------------------------
© Copyright 2012 The Ridgly Group, Inc. All rights reserved. See
http://www.examply.html for important information disclosure.
```

Here's what I expect:

```
***NEW ISSUE SUPPORTED THROUGH UNIVERSALITY   vs 104-13 on AY 3s JAN   
10+BB {MYXV ABC 4116    SM  MYXV YA 102-15 <DO>} | 2010/11 4.0s             4.0s
6+ BB {MYXV ABC 4132    NS  MYXV YT 102-22 <DO>} | 2010 4.5s                4.5s
ABO 2006-OP1 M1     00442PAG5     19-24      p5 
***SECOND SUPPORTED TRHOUGH INVERSALITY GEVINGS                      
10+BB  {NXTW VXA 4061   SL  MYXV YA 103-22 <DO>} | 11 wala 3.5s             3.5s
10+BB  {NXTW VXA 12-47  SP  MYXV YA 106-20 <DO>} | 22 wala 4.0s             4.0s
```

It would be nice it the `***`lines could be eliminated as well.

And here's what I got so far `(?P<header>[\S+\s]+At:.*)\n+(?P<body>[\S+\s]([\d\.\d]+[a-z]?$))` .This doesn't seem to do a good job, as it grabs the dash-lines after the last 4.0s and get stuck at at the non-ascii character `©`. Thanks!

PS: I think the best approach would be to cutoff the header and the tail of the e-mail with groups. So what's left would be the body. Because the header and tail always stay the same, but the body changes on different e-mails. The solution needs not be to specific for an e-mail.

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#module-email.parser?

Comment: If this is some sort of line-oriented record format, why don't you just extract the lines which are in this format? Any line with two `|` characters looks like a starting point, although you might want to add more constraints in order to avoid stray false positives.

Comment: I looked into it but it may not help here since I have a header and a footer, and just want to extract the body. They don't have footer function. I think.

Comment: @tripleee: I think I'm on the right track here. I just getting stuck with the last dash-line and that non-ascii character. My regex grabs the header fine.

Comment: The sample doesn't look like a valid RFC822 message anyway. Could be copy/paste error, of course, but an RFC822 parser is not going to be much help in getting at details within the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you, the lines that you want start with digits followed by a plus sign:

```
^[0-9]*\+.*$
```

This will match the expected output:

```
\*{3}[^\*]*(?:(?=\*{3})|(?=^-*$))
```

> 1. **^**  Matches the beginning of the string.
> 2. **[0-9]** Matches any single character in the range 0-9.
> 3. ***** Matches 0 or more of the preceeding token. This is a greedy match, and will match as many characters as possible before satisfying the next token.
> 4. **\+** Matches a + character.
> 5. **.** Matches any character.
> 6. **$** Matches the end of the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import re
with open("/path/to/file", "r") as fileInput:
    listLines = [   line.strip()
                    for line in fileInput.readlines()
                    if re.match("^[0-9]*\+.*$", line)
                    ] 


for line in listLines:
    print line

>>> 10+BB {MYXV ABC 4116    SM  MYXV YA 102-15 <DO>} | 2010/11 4.0s             4.0s
>>> 6+ BB {MYXV ABC 4132    NS  MYXV YT 102-22 <DO>} | 2010 4.5s                4.5s
>>> 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 4061   SL  MYXV YA 103-22 <DO>} | 11 wala 3.5s             3.5s
>>> 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 12-47  SP  MYXV YA 106-20 <DO>} | 22 wala 4.0s             4.0s
```

Updated to meet new requirements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import re
with open("/path/to/file", "r") as fileInput:
    regex = re.compile(r"\*{3}[^\*]*?(?:(?=^-*$)|(?=\*))", re.MULTILINE)

    listMsg = [ [   line.strip()
                    for line in message.split("\n")
                    if not line.startswith("*") and line.strip()
                    ]
                for message in regex.findall(fileInput.read())
                ]

>>> 10+BB {MYXV ABC 4116    SM  MYXV YA 102-15 <DO>} | 2010/11 4.0s             4.0s
>>> 6+ BB {MYXV ABC 4132    NS  MYXV YT 102-22 <DO>} | 2010 4.5s                4.5s
>>> ABO 2006-OP1 M1     00442PAG5     19-24      p5
>>> 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 4061   SL  MYXV YA 103-22 <DO>} | 11 wala 3.5s             3.5s
>>> 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 12-47  SP  MYXV YA 106-20 <DO>} | 22 wala 4.0s             4.0s
```

Updated to extract the whole body of the email:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import re
with open("/path/to/file", "r") as fileInput:
    regex = re.compile(r"(?<=^At:)([^\n\r]*)(.*?)(?=^-*-$)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

    print regex.search(fileInput.read()).groups()[1]

>>> ACE 2006-OP1 ZZ 111111111 19-24 Z5 ZZW 2012-0P1 SD 222222222 77-00 150
>>> ***NEW ISSUE SUPPORTED THROUGH UNIVERSALITY   vs 104-13 on AY 3s JAN   
>>> 10+BB {MYXV ABC 4116    SM  MYXV YA 102-15 <DO>} | 2010/11 4.0s             4.0s
>>> 6+ BB {MYXV ABC 4132    NS  MYXV YT 102-22 <DO>} | 2010 4.5s                4.5s
>>> ABO 2006-OP1 M1     00442PAG5     19-24      p5 
>>> ***SECOND SUPPORTED TRHOUGH INVERSALITY GEVINGS                      
>>> 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 4061   SL  MYXV YA 103-22 <DO>} | 11 wala 3.5s             3.5s
>>> 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 12-47  SP  MYXV YA 106-20 <DO>} | 22 wala 4.0s             4.0s
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you meant. Will you put down your complete regex solution, please?

Comment: @Mike checkout [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001504/1006989), I updated it with a definition for the patterns

Comment: X.Jacobs: Did you run that code? Here's what I'm getting: `['+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+']` after running you code. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike flawless in my machine, python 2.7, please consider upvoting/accepting responses you might find useful

Comment: X.Jacob: Sorry, I was still figuring out why I was having trouble. I just realized I had omitted one line in my version of text. Please consider tweaking your code accordingly if you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike still the same expected output?

Comment: X.Jacobs: Just updated the expected output. Thanks a lot for you help btw!

Comment: @Mike checkout [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001504/1006989), I updated it to extract the new output

Comment: X.Jacobs: Thanks a lot for your continued help, but I think the best approach would be cutoff the header and the tail of the e-mail with groups. So what's left would be the body. Because the header and tail always stay the same, but the body changes on different e-mails. The solution needs not be to specific for an e-mail. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mike that's basically what that regex does, it will match pretty much anything between the first line starting with `***` until a complete line of dashes, I put it in a second list comprehension to do some filtering in the results, but you might as well skip that to get the whole body of the message, checkout [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001504/1006989), just uncomment the commented block and remove the previous `listMessage` definition, cheers!

Comment: X.Jacobs: Yes! But, not all first lines start with `***`. Some emails skip those star symbols jump right to the body with characters or numbers. Headers always end at the `At: 11/20  9:59:22` line and footers always start with the dash-lines. I'm glad you're not giving up on me :)

Comment: X.Jacobs: If I pass to your script this string it will fail:     `"""RECEIVED: 2012-12-20 09:59:24
SUBJECT: Get Boddy

--- Original Sender: Mark Twain. ---


----- Original Message -----
From: Boby Indo
To: Obum Hunter 
At: 11/20  9:59:22

ACE 2006-OP1 ZZ     111111111     19-24      Z5    
ZZW 2012-0P1 SD     222222222     77-00      150
  
------------------------------------------------------------
Copyright 2012 The Ridgly Group, Inc. All rights reserved. See
http://www.examply.html for important information disclosure."""`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21585/discussion-between-x-jacobs-and-mike)

Comment: @Mike checkout my [re-updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001504/1006989), it will now extract all lines between a line starting with `At:` until a full line of dashes

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s="""RECEIVED: 2012-11 20 09:59:24
... SUBJECT: Get Boddy
... --- Original Sender: Mark Twain. ---
... 
... ----- Original Message -----
... From: Boby Indo
... To: Obum Hunter 
... At: 11/20  9:59:22
... 
... ***NEW ISSUE SUPPORTED THROUGH UNIVERSALITY   vs 104-13 on AY 3s JAN   
... 10+BB {MYXV ABC 4116    SM  MYXV YA 102-15 <DO>} | 2010/11 4.0s             4.0s
... 6+ BB {MYXV ABC 4132    NS  MYXV YT 102-22 <DO>} | 2010 4.5s                4.5s
... ABO 2006-OP1 M1     00442PAG5     19-24      p5 
... ***SECOND SUPPORTED TRHOUGH INVERSALITY GEVINGS
... 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 4061   SL  MYXV YA 103-22 <DO>} | 11 wala 3.5s             3.5s
... 10+BB  {NXTW VXA 12-47  SP  MYXV YA 106-20 <DO>} | 22 wala 4.0s             4.0s
... 
... ------------------------------------------------------------
... © Copyright 2012 The Ridgly Group, Inc. All rights reserved. See
... http://www.examply.html for important information disclosure."""
>>> r=r'(?P<header>\*\*\*[^\n]*)\n(?P<body>[\s\S]*?\n)\n'
>>> for match in re.finditer(r, s):
...     print match.group('body')
... 
10+BB {MYXV ABC 4116    SM  MYXV YA 102-15 <DO>} | 2010/11 4.0s             4.0s
6+ BB {MYXV ABC 4132    NS  MYXV YT 102-22 <DO>} | 2010 4.5s                4.5s

10+BB  {NXTW VXA 4061   SL  MYXV YA 103-22 <DO>} | 11 wala 3.5s             3.5s
10+BB  {NXTW VXA 12-47  SP  MYXV YA 106-20 <DO>} | 22 wala 4.0s             4.0s
```

Comment: Interesting! Never used `finditer()` before. Let me run it and and found out. I'm running python 2.7. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of python are you using? Here's the error I'm getting : `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2'` which is by the way the same error I was getting. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason your solution is not general. i.e if I add another footer (`© Copyright 2012...`), it will then grab that footer. Add a couple of sections of footer separated by dash-lines if you will, and run it again to see what I'm talking about. Thanks!